# Как вставить переменную php в XML

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
$postdata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package login="login" password="password">
<message>
<msg recipient="СЮДА_ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ" sender="mail"
validity_period="86400">И_СЮДА_ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ</msg>
</message>
</package>';
```

Каким образов в подобное можно добавить php переменную?

Comment: почитайте - PHP конкатенация строк

Comment: Так же, как и в html, разве нет? '.$peremennaja.'

Comment: Я просто даже не рассматривал этот вариант. Думал XML это что-то :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable = 'Значение переменной';
$variable2 = 'Значение второй переменной';
$postdata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package login="login" password="password">
<message>
<msg recipient="' . $variable . '" sender="mail"
validity_period="86400">' . $variable2 . '</msg>
</message>
</package>';
```

Второй вариант:

```
$variable = 'Значение переменной';
$variable2 = 'Значение второй переменной';
$postdata = sprint('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package login="login" password="password">
<message>
<msg recipient="%s" sender="mail"
validity_period="86400">%s</msg>
</message>
</package>', $variable, $variable2);
```

Третий вариант:

```
$variable = 'Значение переменной';
$variable2 = 'Значение второй переменной';
$postdata = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
<package login=\"login\" password=\"password\">
<message>
<msg recipient=\"$variable\" sender=\"mail\"
validity_period=\"86400\">$variable2</msg>
</message>
</package>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
$postdata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package login="login" password="password">
<message>
<msg recipient="'.$variable1.'" sender="mail"
validity_period="86400">'.$variable2.'</msg>
</message>
</package>';
```